# Immutable-js: Best way to use referential equality, when searching in List

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I had a little problem with `List.contains()` using `Iterable.is()` instead of `===` to compare values.

```js
var a = immutable.fromJS({a: [1, 2]});
var b = immutable.fromJS({a: [1, 2]});
var l = immutable.List.of(a);

console.log(a === b);       // false
console.log(l.contains(a)); // true
console.log(l.contains(b)); // true, also!
```

I need to check, if list contains exact instance, not a deep clone. I know I can search with a predicate, but maybe there's more clear way.

**UPD:** Here's what I came up with. I just wanted to know if there's more clear way:

```js
var strictContains = function (list, element) {
 return !!list.find(function (value) {
  return value === element;
 });
};
```

Comment: Why do you care about referential equality?

Comment: You might want to try putting wrapper objects (that are compared by reference) in your list.

Comment: @Bergi, my model allows to have several identical objects in the list. And I want to be able to say, if this specific instance is in the list.

Check update in my post.

Comment: I think @Bergi means that as long as the objects are immutable, there is no conceptual difference between a & b. So it doesn't matter which instance is in the list, it's all just data.